# How do I get Next.js 13 app router dynamic URL params from nested server-side component?

Tags: typescript, next.js

This question is about Next.js 13 app router **Server-Side** components:

I understand that in `app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx`, the `slug` parameter is passed to the default function like so:

```
export default function Page({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  return <div>My Post: {params.slug}</div>
}
```

If this renders a deeply nested component, can a component inside get access to the URL `slug`, similar to the `useRouter` hook on client side components?

For example, if in `app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx`, I have:

```
export default function Page({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  return <MyPost/>
}
```

and `MyPost` is:

```
function MyPost() {
  return <div>This is the post: <PostText/></div>
}
```

is there anyway for `PostText` to get `slug` without me having to pass it down through the nested components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible in server components. The only way to fix this is passing the params, or the slug, to your MyPost component as a prop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access the `dynamic URL params` in the `Server components,` it's impossible. You have to drill the params to the component

There is some hooks provided by NextJS but all of them only works in the `client components`

Answer (score 0):

I just built this package to solve that problem:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sodefa/next-server-context

It works like this:

/app/[myParam]/page.tsx

```
import { pageContext } from '@sodefa/next-server-context'
import { NestedServerComponent } from './NestedServerComponent'

export default pageContext.Wrapper(({ params, searchParams }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>MyPage</h1>
      <NestedServerComponent />
    </>
  )
})
```

/app/[myParam]/NestedServerComponent.tsx

```
import { pageContext } from '@sodefa/next-server-context'

export const NestedServerComponent = () => {
  const { params, searchParams } = pageContext.getOrThrow()
  return <div>NestedServerComponent: {params.myParam}</div>
}
```